# Borders in HTML Video

Tags: html

I am not a codewriter. I write a code to show up a video for Streamlabs scene. But in the beginning it show borders. The source is 1080x1080 video. How can I remove them?

```
<head>
<video autoplay>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="420">
</video>
</head>
```

Borders image:

[image: borders image]

Answer (score 1):

Read about `overflow` in CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp
You can use `overflow: hidden`

```
<video autoplay style="overflow: hidden">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="420">
</video>
``
```

Comment: Thank you. It did not fix. Maybe It is about Streamlabs. There is a code section in there.

`body { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); margin: 0px auto; overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: I cut the borders in the software. Thanks for the first code. Fixed